# Change / Set Node Reference field in hook_form_alter

Tags: 7, hooks

I am trying to set the value for an existing Node Reference drop-down field in a content type via hook_form_alter as part of an AJAX call.  The form needs to set values based on a selection, which is does correctly for dozens of fields, but I can't get or find the array structure to change/set the value for a Node Reference field. I've looked around and tried every permutation I can find, including dozens of guesses at what the array structure should look like without any success. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Comment: @Neograph734 of what? every permutation I've tried, I didn't track it. I need the array structure to assign a node value to a node reference field

Comment: Looking at the code I guess that should be an array of nids, like this: `array(array('nid' => 1))` (single value field) or `array(array('nid' => 1), array('nid' => 2))` (multi value).

Comment: Node Reference as in provided by the obsolete References module? Or an Entity Reference?

Comment: it should be an array of nodes, but the exact structure eludes me: for example where a text field would be something like $form['field_name'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#value'] = 'abc', I don't know the corresponding structure and relevant names for a reference field

Comment: @Clive using the References module, which I won't be permitted to change

Comment: Yeah not really sure why I felt the need to include "obsolete" in there :) The field column is `nid`, definitely (and `uid` for users`). So `$form['field_name'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['nid']['#default_value'] = 123;`, or, if it's a weird one,  `$form['field_name'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['nid']['#default_value'] = 123;`. Depending on desired outcome, `#default_value` might turn to `#value`, at which point the widget type should be set to `hidden` to avoid confusing users

Comment: Not sure what happened to that comment, the markup's right. Hopefully you can still read it. To set further items, by the way, increment the delta: `$form['field_name'][LANGUAGE_NONE][1]['nid']['#default_value‌​'] = 345;`

Comment: @Clive thanks, but none of those have any effect.  They don't give an error, but they don't set the value. There's no default set, and no actions on saving the content. I don't know what would define it as weird, but there's no custom hooks that affect this field until the hook_form_alter, and nothing after that

Comment: A field can't choose whether a hook gets invoked for it, core decides that. Unless the references module implement hook_module_implements_alter` and nukes them or something, but I'm pretty sure it won't do that. So yeah, definitely in weird territory. I would go and edit a node that has an existing value for that field, `dpm` out the form field at that point, and see what structure it has. Logically you just need to reproduce that

Comment: I had tried that as well, which should put it at $form['field_name'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#default_value'][0], but that also has no effect when set; but your previous comment gave another idea to try which finally did work - $form['field_name'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#value'][0] = '123';  Thanks! If you don't, I'll add that as an answer

Comment: Go for it @Geoff, the exact thing you used to solve it would probably be more useful to people in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

With Clive's help, I was able to figure out the array structure I needed. To set the node ID for a Node Reference field (References Module) in hook_form_alter, this structure worked for me:

```
$form['field_name'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#value'][0] = {node id}
```